# Git subtree with add-ons that have a themes folder

Tags: add-on-development, git

I've taken to installing add-ons that I have in development in separate repositories as submodules into each of my EE projects. This has worked fine for add-ons that do not have a themes folder, but I am now finally in the situation where I want to develop a module/extension that utilizes a themes folder.

I have come accross [this other question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41/add-on-development-with-themes-and-git) for which answers suggest using symlinks to accomplish the goal. I find symlinks in git to be a scary proposition (they don't behave the same across platforms), and would prefer to have a way to do this that refers to the remote repo, not a local copy by a strict path.

Is there a way to use subtree merging to remap e.g.:

- `subproject/system/expressionengine/third_party/add-on-name` to `project/third_party/add-on-name` (I use ee-master-config to remap third_party outside of the expressionengine directory, along with the templates directory)
- `subproject/themes/third_party/add-on-name` to `project/public_html/themes/third_party/add-on-name` (I keep the system folder above web root)?

To clarify the setup, this is my current folder hierarchy for any given EE site:

```
/public_html
  /public_html/themes
  /public_html/system (contains only an index.php pointing to ../../system)
/system
/templates
/third_party
```

Web root is set to public_html so that executable server side code is never exposed to the wider world. In an add-on repository the folder structure is that of the default expressionengine setup, eg.:

```
/system
  /system/expressionengine/third_party
/themes
```

The trouble then is including the files from the add-on repository to different paths in an expressionengine site's hierarchy.

Comment: Could you explain what your issue(s) is(/are) with symlinks? Just tested making symlinks with relative paths on a mac, in windows they turn into unusable shortcuts. You can't make "symlinks" easily either. However, if you neither need to create nor modify symlinks I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: @notacouch The real issue with symlinks is that I'm developing in a [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) virtual machine with NFS to share the document root with the vm. NFS does not carry over symlinks outside of the shared root, where the source repository for the add-on is. (I'm not certain from a cursory search but it also seems that symlinks to files inside the shared root are also ignored)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too well versed in Git, but you could override the third party path for addon's in the `system/expressionengine/config/config.php` file and put site & addon assets in a folder outside of the EE system files with these overrides:

```
$config['third_party_path'] = '/server/path/domain.com/assets/addon_sys/';
$config['path_third_themes'] = '/server/path/domain.com/assets/addon_themes/';
$config['url_third_themes'] = '/assets/addon_themes/';
```

I typically put all site assets in one folder, so everything is easy to access:

```
/assets/addon_sys/
/assets/addon_themes/
/assets/css/
/assets/js/
/assets/img/
/assets/low_vars/
/assets/templates/
/assets/uploads/
```

Comment: First, thanks for taking a look at this. However, I am already remaping the third_party path via ee-master-config. This only shows an alternative folder structure, the problem of merging in a separate repository (the addon's) is still at issue. :(

Comment: I know this is tricky. Hopefully some more experienced Git users can chime in.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this is not possible with `git-subtree`.

Taking the code example from the [kernel.org docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html):

```
$ git remote add -f Bproject /path/to/B
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit Bproject/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=dir-B/ -u Bproject/master
$ git commit -m "Merge B project as our subdirectory"
```

In the `read-tree` command on line 3 you can only set a single `--prefix` value (which is where we set the subdirectory of the man project to target for the subtree merge).  What you describe would require multiple values with some way to match subtree paths to main project paths.

I do feel your pain with this issue - I've hit the same problem with both client builds using 3rd party addons and with building addons myself. I don't think it's a solved problem so I'd love to hear what you come up with!

As an aside, I've not had issues with checking in symlinks, but then I don't work outside of a mac + Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished getting my setup with git working the way I want. symlinks definitely made things easier but seeing how they're not viable in your case... perhaps just stick with keeping the full themes directory in your submodule and adding it in to the main project after your work is done.

One is [apenwarr's git-subtree script](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/)

> The main difference is that, besides merging the other project as a
>   subdirectory, you can also extract the entire history of a
>   subdirectory from your project and make it into a standalone project.
>   Unlike the subtree merge strategy you can alternate back and forth
>   between these two operations. If the standalone library gets updated,
>   you can automatically merge the changes into your project; if you
>   update the library inside your project, you can "split" the changes
>   back out again and merge them back into the library project.

Though I'm not quite sure how you'd work with only a path of the add-on repo.

Maybe it's easier without the git-subtree script, e.g. following the [q-a here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12048161/781824):

To start off:

```
$ git remote add Bar /path/to/bar
$ git merge -s ours --no-commit Bar/master
$ git read-tree --prefix=public_html/themes/third_party -u Bar/master:/themes/third_party
```

When pulling later:

```
$ get fetch Bar
$ git pull -X subtree=public_html/themes/third_party Bar master
```

How are you working with actual third party add-ons whose developers release updates and/or require changes on your own?

Comment: Thanks, I had seen the git-subtree script and come to the same conclusions as you. For other developer's addons I tend to just copy over files manually and commit them with the project. This is less viable when the project is my own and in active development, requiring a lot of syncing (though right now I'm automating that with a bash script that does some cp's).